# Why does JQuery keydown work for window but not textbox?

Tags: jquery

Why does this work:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

but not this:

```
$('#ajaxSearchText').keydown(function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

I'm testing with Firefox 3.
Interestingly, neither of them work in IE7.

Comment: Suggestion: provide the smallest possible self-contained example that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checked this in Chrome, IE7 and Firefox 3.0.3. Works as it should. jQuery version 1.2.6.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(function() 
      {
        $("#ajaxSearchText").keydown(function(event)
        {
          alert(event.keyCode);
        });
      });
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <input type="text" id="ajaxSearchText"></input>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

To fix the issues in IE6 and IE7, try this...

```
$(function() 
{
    $(document).keydown(function(event){
        alert(event.keyCode);
    });
});
```

Attaching the event to the `$(document)` seems to be the magic things here.

Your first bit of code really should work in IE as well though. It seems to be down to a bug in jQuery that will hopefully be fixed soon...

Here is a link to the bug report in jQuery. https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3614

Comment: this bug report was closed as 'not a bug' because key events are not supported on 'window'

Comment: Also refer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717897/jquery-keydown-on-div-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 3):

For all your keydown/keyup/keyboard needs, use the jQuery hotkeys plugin.

Saw this a few months ago and it never fails to impress it. Follow the jump for the plugin demo ... http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/

It maps ALL keys on a keyboard including combos. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll add a comment to help anyone who stumbles across this like I did.

The version of this plugin that works on jQuery 1.4.2 and later is here: http://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/

Comment: jQuery already had everything that is needed to answer this question, a plugin won't really help.

Comment: Sorry ars265, that's plain wrong. DO tell us how you could easily use native jQuery to capture ctrl + alt + del. And if you use ascii/key codes you've already lost...

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$('#ajaxSearchText').keyup(function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

works for me perfectly. Also check the id of the textarea

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#searchInput').keydown(function() {
    alert('testing');
});
```

will not work. However, if you wrap it in a function:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#searchInput').keydown(function() {
        alert('testing');
    });
});
```

it will work.

Without that function declaration, it only works on objects like document and window.

Answer (score -1):

Because key events are not supported on the 'window' object.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

But only on 'document':

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

If it ever worked then it was a bug in jQuery.