# Angujarjs Image Silider keypress bind not working and

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have make image slider in angularjs with google material. My slider is working but I have two issue

1. I could not bind keypress
2. My images are sliding but both side together and then first hide after few seconds

Some code is over here

```
$scope.onKeyUp = function (keyCode) {
                console.log("I am here;")
                if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
                    $scope.prevSlide;
                } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
                    $scope.nextSlide;
                }
            }
```

and full codepen is https://codepen.io/milindsaraswala/pen/yJaYpe

Kindly somebody help, what can be the issue.

Comment: firstly, it should be $event.keyCode.
secondly, i am getting a lot of other errors in your pen

Comment: @gaurav5430 Error are just for images nothing else

Comment: also, where have you put ng-keyup , so that your onkeyup function gets called ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 I removed all the error and keyUp is ng-keypress is on line number 40 in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are a few things that you would need to change.

First, you ought to know that keypress/keydown would only work on elements which can receive focus (like input elements).

A hack to do that is to specify tabindex on your element.
[AngularJS ng-keydown directive only working for <input> context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704771/angularjs-ng-keydown-directive-only-working-for-input-context)

```
<div class="slider" tabindex="0" ng-keyup="onKeyUp($event)"  flex></div>
```

Secondly, you need to use keyup event instead of keypress, as it seems that keypress is deprecated.

This is the updated codepen.
https://codepen.io/gaurav5430/pen/xOEXzG/

`console.log` is being called for `keypress` now (not sure if your logic is working or not)

You will need to click once on the slider to focus it (or use keyboard to focus)