# my jquery plugin doesn't work on jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

Here is my jquery plugin, it doesn't do much but not work. What do I do wrong?

```
(function($) {

jQuery.fn.myTest = function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.on('keyup', function(){
        $(this).after('<div>event</div>');
    })
    return this;
}

}(jQuery));    
$(".test").myTest();
alert('asasfd')
```

no alerts or div appended . Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/vfDKj/3/

Comment: It is working fine....

Comment: Ya working as expected

Comment: It is working fine also here

Comment: Oh, seems browser issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working fine. Here is a screenshot of it working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plugin 'should' work - but be careful as the 'keyup' only applies to elements that can have focus.

[jQuery - keydown() on div not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717897/jquery-keydown-on-div-not-working-in-firefox)

add `<div id="testdiv" tabindex="0"></div>` to the div to give it focus.

Also, I'd wrap the `$(".test").myTest();` in a doc ready function to be safe.
http://jsfiddle.net/Reubenator/QFYzu/

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change jQuery to neawer one such as 2.0.x and the press Run. Whole script looks fine and action is being provided after key up on the input. Moreover, please describe what realy doesn't work. If alert doesn't appear it means that something is wrong on your side - maybe your browser has the javascript turned off?