# ReactJS - Why does `event.keyCode == 16` not work but `event.shiftKey` return `true`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycode, mouseclick-event

I have a react component that's trying to pick up a shift + click on a component.

```
handleClick(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 16) { 
    // do stuff
  }
}

render() {
  // ...

  <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
    // ...
  </div>

  // ...
}
```

For some reason the `e.keyCode` returns `undefined` so it never fires. But it works with `e.shiftKey` which returns `true`.

I use `e.keyCode` in plenty of other click events so is there any reason it wouldn't work with the SHIFT key (+ click) specifically?

Using Firefox 66.0.3. Thanks!

Comment: How can you get the keyCode on mouse click..?

Comment: Add a keyboard event on the shift button press

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717897/jquery-keydown-on-div-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: Don't use `keyCode`, it's deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: `e` is a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) and doesn't have a `.keyCode` property. (also, this question has nothing to do with React)